# Querying rows in multiple ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

How should I store multiple `start` and `end` "follow" date ranges in **post_follow** and query for all the post_changes to **post_id** within specified time ranges?

Currently, I have a tables:

**post_follow**:

```
(
  user_id int,
  post_id int,
  start date,
  end date
)
```

and

**post_changes**:

```
(
  post_id: int,
  -- ...
  time timestamp
)
```

However, I want to add the option to unfollow/follow posts but still show the post_changes that occurred during the ranges of time that the user "follow"ed the post.

e.g. **follow** @ 1/1/14, **unfollow** @ 1/5/14, **follow** @ 1/10/14 ... So, in this case, I'd want to show the changes in the followed post between 1/1/14 and 1/5/14 and between 1/10/14 and the current date.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a `follow boolean`? 
And PostgreSQL has range types timestamp range type `tsrange`, and dates range `daterange`.
 It will make your queries easier.

Please see the PostgreSQL documentation about ranges and operators on them:

[Postgresql Range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html)
[Range operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE)